# java com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: The document has no page root

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to read a PDF files and I got this exception

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: The document has no page root (meaning: it's an invalid PDF).
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPages(PdfReader.java:1248)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:739)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:181)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:219)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:207)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:197)
    at com.mitech.med.watermark.Test2.main(Test2.java:11)
```

I used itext 5.5.10.
This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:/Users/matteo.fusi/Downloads/testPDF/1142.pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is the link to the PDF document:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2IrLGj9wefRVFZxSUhkN0o0N1k/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Regards

Matteo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same issue on itext 5.5.10. I haven't taken a look yet on some new changes on the latest version. But it's working fine on itext 5.3.4. You could try on that version

Comment: *it's working fine on itext 5.3.4* - **working fine** should mean **rejecting the PDF** as it is broken.

Comment: Thanks! I tested on iText 5.5.5 and worked fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

The PDF in question is broken.

This is the page tree root dictionary object:

```
1 0 obj
<</Type /Pages /Count 1
/Kids[
4 0 R
]
/Type /Page
/MediaBox [ 0 0 595 842 ]
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Resources <<
/Font << /F0 6 0 R /F1 7 0 R /F2 8 0 R /F3 9 0 R /F4 10 0 R /F5 11 0 R /F6 12 0 R /F7 13 0 R /F8 14 0 R /F9 15 0 R /F10 16 0 R /F11 17 0 R /F12 18 0 R /F13 19 0 R /F14 20 0 R >>
/XObject <<
 /Im0 5 0 R >>
>>
>>endobj
```

As you see the key **Type** occurs twice, once with value **Pages** and once with value **Page**. But the specification ISO 32000-1 clearly states in section 7.3.7 - Dictionary Objects:

> Multiple entries in the same dictionary shall not have the same key.

(This, by the way, is a fairly obvious requirement for dictionary objects in general...)

---

The result of such a defect may be different in different PDF processors, the major obvious cases:

- They might explicitly check for such problems and reject the file outright.
- They might not check but use the first value assigned to the key.
- They might not check but use the last value assigned to the key.

iText appears to be of the third kind. As far as iText is concerned, therefore, the page tree root dictionary has a **Type** value **Page**. But the specification requires the **Type** of a page tree node to be **Pages**. Thus, iText throws the observed exception.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would try an alternative that seems to work for a lot of people :

http://pdfbox.apache.org/ <- Inspired by an older post I researchd on stack overflow

Secondly while debugging the issue I found this

```
rootPages == null || (!PdfName.PAGES.equals(rootPages.get(PdfName.TYPE)) 
&& !PdfName.PAGES.equals(rootPages.get(new PdfName("Types"))))
```

Is not satisfied hence your problem. I believe it might be a current Bug in Itext.

DFTBA

Comment: *"I believe it might be a current Bug in Itext."* - Why do you believe so? (In a way that expression indeed is wrong but only because it is ***too lax*** and allows **Types** as alternative to **Type**.)